# Can someone help as to why I am getting an argument error flask on_model_delete callback?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to implement a callback so that when I delete an employee that has an associated image, the `on_model_delete` callback will remove it from the local system.

This is my code:

```
class EmployeeView(ModelView):
    form = EmployeeForm

    def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
        if not model.photo:
            return ''
        return Markup('<img height="100" width="100" src="%s">' %  url_for('static',
                                              filename= 'images/' +   model.photo.image))
    column_formatters = {
        'photo': _list_thumbnail
    }

    form_extra_fields = {
        'photo': ImageUploadField('Image', base_path=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    }

    def on_model_delete():
        if app.config['USE_S3']:
            pass
        else:
            os.remove(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + model.photo.image)

    def is_accessible(self):
        return flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated
```

The methods defined and the variables with the dictionaries are all parameters that `Flask-Admin` provides for customizing its views. The `on_model_change` callback is provided by flask_admin. Documentation is here [enter link description here](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/)

Here is what I've implemented and the errors that I've received with them:

```
on_model_delete(model) ---------> TypeError: on_model_delete() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

on_model_delete(model.photo) -----------> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

on_model_delete() -----------> TypeError: on_model_delete() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

I'm so confused, depending on what I put the argument list keeps changing. When I put nothing it says 2 was given. When I put one argument it says two was given. What is going on?

Comment: Can you please appropriately format your code? I'm assuming that your indentation is slightly off. Is `on_model_delete()` supposed to be a method of your EmployeeView class? If so, it needs a `self` input at the very least.

Comment: Also what is this `model` that you're passing to `on_model_delete()`. As it is, your `on_model_delete` accepts no inputs

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Suever, I've formatted the code and edited the question with more context. `on_model_delete(model)` is from `flask_admin.contrib.sqla`. I'm trying to pass in an `Employee` model that has an associated `Photo` object `has_one`. I've tried it with and without arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs this is the correct method definition.

```
def on_model_delete(self, model):
    pass
```

https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/model/base/#BaseModelView.on_model_delete

Yours is different. You miss both `self` and `model`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should have looked at the source. I got confused because `on_model_delete(model)` is defined in `flask_admin.contrib.sqla` and on `flask_admin.model`.